# ERROR Parsing a JSONObject inside a JSONArray Android

Tags: android, arrays, json

I am developing an Android application which fetches data from a server through HTTP GET, stores the response (JSON format) in a String. I want to parse the String and get the values within the JSONArray.

The received JSON which is stored in the STRING is :

```
{
    "code": 1,
    "data": {
        "moodGraphData": {
            "myself": {
                "1": {
                    "id": "999999999",
                    "value": "4.3",
                    "name": "Myself",
                    "owner": "",
                    "type": 1,
                    "children": []
                }
            },
            "my_teams": [],
            "my_units": [],
            "companies": [
                {
                    "id": "4",
                    "name": "Testing",
                    "owner": "Ankur Ankur",
                    "value": "3.4",
                    "type": "4",
                    "children": {
                        "0": {
                            "id": "10",
                            "value": 3.8,
                            "name": "Mun tiimi",
                            "owner": "",
                            "type": 5,
                            "children": [],
                            "count": 1
                        },
                        "4": {
                            "id": "31",
                            "value": 3.05,
                            "name": "gmail.com",
                            "owner": "",
                            "type": 5,
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "id": "27",
                                    "value": 2.3,
                                    "name": "Priidu Team2",
                                    "owner": " ",
                                    "type": 5,
                                    "children": [],
                                    "count": 1
                                }
                            ],
                            "count": 2
                        },
                        "6": {
                            "id": "50",
                            "value": 2.95,
                            "name": "gmail.com",
                            "owner": "",
                            "type": 5,
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "id": "51",
                                    "value": 2.6,
                                    "name": "Testing",
                                    "owner": "Ujjwal Mairh",
                                    "type": 5,
                                    "children": [],
                                    "count": 1
                                }
                            ],
                            "count": 2
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "companyTopStatements": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "text": "I am happy at work today",
                "key": "Mood",
                "answer": "3.5"
            },
            {
                "id": "8",
                "text": "I am using my strengths at work",
                "key": "Strengths",
                "answer": "3.5"
            },
            {
                "id": "11",
                "text": "My opinions matter and I can influence in my work",
                "key": "Influence",
                "answer": "3.5"
            }
        ],
        "companyBottomStatements": [
            {
                "id": "13",
                "text": "I am surrounded by teammates who are motivated and doing great things",
                "key": "Team",
                "answer": "3.2"
            },
            {
                "id": "14",
                "text": "I have a close friends at work",
                "key": "Friendship",
                "answer": "3.2"
            },
            {
                "id": "15",
                "text": "I receive frequent feedback in order to progress in my role",
                "key": "Feedback",
                "answer": "3.2"
            }
        ]
    },
    "errors": null
}
```

I want to parse the JSON Array **"companyTopStatements"**, and retrieve the value in **"key"**, which is inside a JSONObject.

The code I used is as follows :

```
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(Get_MyCompany_JSON);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("companyTopStatements");
        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
        {
          JSONObject curr = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                      String keyValue = curr.getString("key");
          Log.d("Key",keyValue);
        }
```

I am unable to parse it and obtaining an exception :

```
04-08 21:25:03.561: W/System.err(13464):        org.json.JSONException: No value for companyTopStatements
04-08 21:25:03.561: W/System.err(13464):    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
04-08 21:25:03.561: W/System.err(13464):    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:548)
04-08 21:25:03.561: W/System.err(13464):    at com.moodwonder.fi.HTTP_SignIn_Thread.doInBackground(HTTP_SignIn_Thread.java:105)
04-08 21:25:03.561: W/System.err(13464):    at com.moodwonder.fi.HTTP_SignIn_Thread.doInBackground(HTTP_SignIn_Thread.java:1)
04-08 21:25:03.561: W/System.err(13464):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-08 21:25:03.561: W/System.err(13464):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
04-08 21:25:03.561: W/System.err(13464):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
04-08 21:25:03.561: W/System.err(13464):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
04-08 21:25:03.561: W/System.err(13464):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
04-08 21:25:03.566: W/System.err(13464):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> org.json.JSONException: No value for companyTopStatements

You have a json object node at the top but JSONArray `companyTopStatements` is not under that json object.

```
{ // json object node 
    "code": 1,
    "data": { // json object data
```

Under data you have

```
"companyTopStatements": [
```

You have the JSONArray `companyTopStatements` under JSONObject `data`.

You can confirm by pasting the json @

http://www.jquery4u.com/demos/online-json-tree-viewer/#

```
 JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(Get_MyCompany_JSON);
 JSONObject jb = jsonObj.getJSONObject("data");
 JSONArray jsonArray = jb.getJSONArray("companyTopStatements");
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I assumed that companyTopStatements is a stand alone JSONArray. The JSON tree View really helps in getting it right.

Answer (score 4):

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(Get_MyCompany_JSON);
JSONObject jsondata = jsonObj.getJSONObject("data");
JSONArray jsonArray = jsondata.getJSONArray("companyTopStatements");
for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
{
  JSONObject curr = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
  String keyValue = curr.getString("key");
  Log.d("Key",keyValue);
 }
```

You forgot `companyTopStatements` is in `data` object

Comment: Thank you. Your solution fixed it. I could'nt read the closing brace of data-object properly. I assumed that companyTopStatements is a stand alone JSONArray.